# Looking for a good trackball, comparable to D-Control ES trackball

Tags: trackball, pro-tools, control

Hi,

Recently I've worked on a D-control ES, which was a real treat. Beautifull and thoughtfull design. Especially the embedded keyboard. trackball and screen arm swing are really great.
Ever since working on it I miss the trackball especially. Normally I use a Wacom Bamboo, but sometimes in PT it's just not the right thing for the job. Specially scrolling through sessions was such a breeze with the trackball in the D-Control. The inertia, because of the weight of the ball, works magic. Just give it a jank and stop it where you need to be.

Anyway, is there something comparable on the market, since I can't afford the real deal :)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Update: bought the kensington expert mouse, so far so good! Thanks!!

Arnoud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Kensington Expert Mouse is, in my opinion, the best thing out there.](http://www.kensington.com/kensington/us/us/p/1444/K64325/expert-mouse%C2%AE.aspx)

I program my 4 most used keystrokes to the extra buttons and I can really fly with this thing.

Comment: +1 on the Kensington. They're little tanks too; i've never seen one die (touch wood).

Comment: I'm usually a Bamboo user as well, but tend to use the Kensington a lot (mostly because they're on a lot of the systems at school). If you wanna see one die within a couple weeks, get 70+ students to use them all day, every day. ;)

That said, they're fantastic little devices.